# Theme for text files in Sublime Text 3

Tags: text, themes, sublimetext3, editor, sidebar

Since one of the last updates the theme for .txt files in my Sublime Text 3 has changed. I am currently using the Monokai Theme for Sublime and would like to have the same theme options for all file types (black background, line numbers on the left, slim right sidebar/margin). Only when opening .txt files the background switches to white and the sidebars/margins become too wide taking half of the screen space.

An example can be seen on the left side of the screenshot. on the right side my sublime settings are displayed:
[image]

I have tried changing the "Preferences" -> "Color Scheme... " to any other color scheme. The changes seem to apply to the other file types I use (.json, .csv, .py etc). Only the .txt files seem not to be affected by any scheme changes.

Changing "Preferences" -> "Theme..." doesn't change much.

Neither could I find any specific settings for .txt files in "Preferences" -> "Settings".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two potential sources of the problem - an overzealous plugin or a messed-up `.sublime-settings` file. First, look in your `Packages/User` directory, where `Packages` is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

In the `User` directory, look for files named `Text.sublime-settings` or `Markdown*.sublime-settings`, then try deleting them (or renaming them to `*.bak` so they won't get processed).

If that doesn't work, take the list of all installed plugins from `Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings` and put it in your user preferences in the `"ignored_packages"` setting. Hopefully that will solve the problem. To identify the offending plugin, start removing plugins from `"ignored_packages"` one at a time until the behavior comes back.

Comment: The second solution worked for me, thank you. The issue was caused by "MarkdownEditing" package,  putting it to the ignore list solved the issue. This, however, caused an error to appear on every sublime restart. To get rid of that issue, see [here](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing/issues/485).

Comment: @GinTonic Ah yes, MarkdownEditing - I recalled having a similar problem to you 5 or 6 years ago, but I couldn't remember the exact plugin - just that it had to do with Markdown. Glad you found the problem!